# Volume of the polytope while its vertices moving

Tags: geometry

Here are $k$ vertices in a convex polytope in $R^n (k+1 \ge n)$.

Each vertex are moving (with constant velocity) as time goes from $t=0$ to $1$, keeping up the convexity with $k$ vertices.

My question is that the volume can be expressed as a polynomial in t or not.

If so, what is the degree of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

You mean perhaps the $k$ points are all of the vertices of the polytope  without repeats at all times $t$. Then yes, the volume is a polynomial in $t$ of degree $\le n$. The idea is to decompose the polytope into simplexes and to see that the decomposition is still valid at all times $t$. Then it's enough to see this fact for a simplex. Note that for all the simplexes in the decomposition  the determinants giving their volumes have a fixed sign. Note that each entry of the determinant is either $1$ for the elements of the first column or a polynomial in $t$ of degree $1$.

The polynomial may be constant ( if all the points are translated with the same speed) or a multiple of $t^n$ in the case of dilations.

We need the condition that the points do not collide. As an example on $\mathbb{R}$ the points $0$ and $t$ give a polytope of volume $|t|$. This is a polynomial function if $t$ in in an interval not containing $0$ in interior.

Answer (score 1):

A generalization of the [shoelace formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) to $n$ dimensions will allow you to express the volume as a linear combination of determinants of $n$-by-$n$ matrices whose entries are coordinates of the vertices. In other words, the volume is a polynomial function in $n(k+1)$ variables of degree $n$.

Now that you assume that the coordinates of the vertices are affine functions of $t$, the volume becomes a polynomial in $t$ of degree $n$.